# How to use ::ng-deep in media print{ }

Tags: html, css

I need to use ::ng-deep in media print{ } but it's not working. How can i achieve this?

```
 @media print { 

    ::ng-deep.page-header {
      
        display:none !important;
      
   }
}
```

Comment: Try nesting @media inside ng-deep (haven't tried myself yet)

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work. @Shubanker